# MoSync: Java Started but Returned Exit Code 13

Tags: java, android, frameworks, mosync

I want to start making android apps using `MoSync` but when I tried to run `MoSync` for the first time, confronted with this error:

http://s3.picofile.com/file/8197460276/Capture.PNG

In addition, I have ran eclipse and android studio without java errors and tried lots of solutions mentioned in other posts. I will appreciate it whether you can give me solutions to **start mosync without errors**.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve the problem acting like this:
1. First, I uninstalled `MoSync v2.7` (which was installed).
2. Then, I downloaded `MoSync v4.0 Alpha` and installed it.
3. After that I uninstalled *ALL* the Java Kits and tools from `Control Panel`.
4. Then I installed `Java(TM) Development Kit version 6 update 45 i568`.
5. Finally, I acted like what `MoSync` said and copied `jre` folder into `MoSync` folder.
Finish.
It amazingly worked for me!